# Extracting strings from a directory full of files

Tags: python, string, file, split

Problem:
I have a directory of over 7000 files (sometimes more, sometimes less.)
None of these files have a file extension.
Each file has an unknown coding (most likely binary), but I can seem to read it a single file in with basic code IF i add an extension to the file. Since it's not ANSI or UTF-8 encoded, Replace and Strip functions don't work for the spaces. This module now works for single files.(thanks AKX)

CODE:

```
# OPEN FILES
import re
f = open('berlin_floors_metal_catwalk1.txt','r')
filecontent = f.read()

# ---SPECULAR---
# FIND SPECULAR NAME
identifiers = re.findall("([~_a-z0-9]{3,})", filecontent, flags=re.I)
specfname = identifiers[identifiers.index('envMapParms') - 1]
specular = specfname + '.png'
#---- THE FINAL VARIABLE
print(specular)
# --------------

# ---NORMAL---
# FIND NORMAL NAME
identifiers = re.findall("([~_a-z0-9]{3,})", filecontent, flags=re.I)
normalfname = identifiers[identifiers.index('specularMap') - 1]
normal = normalfname + '.png'
#---- THE FINAL VARIABLE
print(normal)
# --------------

# ---DIFFUSE COLORMAP---
# FIND COLORMAP NAME
identifiers = re.findall("([~_a-z0-9]{3,})", filecontent, flags=re.I)
colorfname = identifiers[identifiers.index('colorMap') - 1]
colormap = colorfname + '.png'
#---- THE FINAL VARIABLE
print(colormap)
# --------------

f.close()
```

INPUT:

`²   Ï

@           Ð    p
         @   d   î     Ï   ÷            ,  S  ÍÌL?ÍÌL@  ˆÀ   ?_    €?  €?  €?  €?i        €?      €?l_sm_t0c0n0s0_sco berlin_floors_metal_catwalk1 berlin_floors_metal_catwalk1_c colorMap normalMap berlin_floors_metal_catwalk1_n specularMap ~berlin_floors_metal_catwalk1~f0baafa8 envMapParms colorTint dynamicFoliageSunDiffuseMinMax`

OUTPUT:

```
~berlin_floors_metal_catwalk1~f0baafa8.png
berlin_floors_metal_catwalk1_n.png
berlin_floors_metal_catwalk1_c.png
```

Comment: have you tried opening the files as csv?  The first character is creating issues

Comment: no I haven't as yet.

Comment: I think you're actually trying to read a binary file that just happens to contain these texture filename references. You'd have a better time writing a real parser for the binary format. Where are these files actually from, what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: It's from the Call of Duty series of games. Call of Duty 4, World at War and Black Ops 1. These are the Material files that the asset editor spits out after you have set up an image. Unfortunately, these are not cross-compatible to Black Ops 3. I think the file probably IS binary, but so far, so good. What I am doing is creating 3 Variables to insert into a template to output a new (compatible) GDT material file for use with Black Ops 3.

Answer (score 0):

While I still stand by my comment that you should figure out the binary format of the file, a regular expression to find all long enough (here 3+ characters) identifier-like strings might just work out for you in this particular case. I've embedded the `data` from your post here, but you could as well read it from the file:

```py
import re

data = """
®   Î       @           P    ˆ
         @   d   ð     Î   ù       %   1  X  ÍÌL?ÍÌL@  ˆÀ   ?d    €?  €?  €?  €?n        €?      €?l_sm_r0c0n0s0 okinawa_ceiling_concrete_bunker okinawa_ceiling_concrete_bunker_c colorMap normalMap okinawa_ceiling_concrete_bunker_n specularMap ~okinawa_floor_concrete_spott~c12191f9 envMapParms colorTint dynamicFoliageSunDiffuseMinMax

²   Ï
"""

identifiers = re.findall("([~_a-z0-9]{3,})", data, flags=re.I)

print(identifiers)
```

outputs

```
[
    "l_sm_r0c0n0s0",
    "okinawa_ceiling_concrete_bunker",
    "okinawa_ceiling_concrete_bunker_c",
    "colorMap",
    "normalMap",
    "okinawa_ceiling_concrete_bunker_n",
    "specularMap",
    "~okinawa_floor_concrete_spott~c12191f9",
    "envMapParms",
    "colorTint",
    "dynamicFoliageSunDiffuseMinMax",
]
```

Comment: I wish I had the know-how on how to read the binary format, but the training just simply isn't there. I've taken 3 days to come up with what I have by scouring the internet. (especially here).  What you have done may work to a degree, As you can see in my amateur code, I have specfname, normfname and colorfname as the three final variable names. I'm not sure how I could assign each one to the correct line using your code as all of the files are different lengths, and the filenames may end up on different lines.

Comment: It looks like, for whichever reason, in this particular file, the colormap filename comes before `colorMap`, so you can use `identifiers.index('colorMap')` to find `colorMap`, then subtract one; `colorfname = identifiers[identifiers.index('colorMap') - 1]`, etc. I fear that won't be bullet-proof though.

Answer (score 0):

This code is now complete and the code is updated to reflect the changes.
Big Thank you to [AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51685/akx)